# Pyenv shim not created when installing package using setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, pyenv

When I install a package into a pyenv environment by using `./setup.py install`, the package's script is not added to pyenv's shim directory.  As a result, the script is not in my PATH and cannot be executed normally.

My package is using setuptools.  My package's `setup.py` specifies a script that should be installed.

```
SCRIPTS = [
    'bin/olio_msg_send_test_messages',
]
setup(
    ...
    scripts=SCRIPTS,
    ...
)
```

When I install the package using:

```
./setup.py build
./setup.py install
```

Then the script gets installed into the package's directory:

```
...
Installing olio_msg_send_test_messages script to /home/wayne/.pyenv/versions/2.6.9/bin
...
```

And the file is indeed there:

```
$ ls -l /home/wayne/.pyenv/versions/2.6.9/bin/olio_msg_send_test_messages 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 wayne wayne 240 Apr 20 09:30 /home/wayne/.pyenv/versions/2.6.9/bin/olio_msg_send_test_messages
```

However, no shim is added to [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv)'s shims directory:

```
$ ls -l ~/.pyenv/shims/olio_msg_send_test_messages 
ls: cannot access /home/wayne/.pyenv/shims/olio_msg_send_test_messages: No such file or directory
```

Therefore the script is not in my PATH and cannot be executed by typing its name.

What do I need to do so that the pyenv shim gets created when I install the package via `./setup.py install`?

---

Versions:

- pyenv 20141118
- python 2.6.7

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Versions of pyenv before v20141211 do not automatically "rehash" (that is, update shims) when a new package is installed.  To get pyenv to automatically rehash, either upgrade to a newer version of pyenv, or install the [pyenv-pip-refresh](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-pip-rehash) plugin.

To rehash manually, use this command for *bash*:

```
pyenv rehash && hash -r
```

or this command for `zsh`:

```
pyenv rehash && rehash
```

(The rehash instructions are from *yyuu* in a reply to [this github issue](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/issues/31))